# how to migrate a unity project to an older version

Tags: unity-game-engine

I transferred my project from version 2020.3.30f1 to version 2023.2.8f1. And now I can’t build it, I tried everything but the build just doesn’t work on this version, so please help me transfer it to an older version without errors

Comment: well, you could probably fix the build issue.. the obvious answer is to roll back your source control until the time of working.

Comment: as mentioned A) **Use source control!** Such as e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com) or [Unity Version Control](https://unity.com/solutions/git) .. B) jumping **3 years** in Unity versions is a huge leap! **IF** you do this for whatever reason you make **backups** first (if not having A) in place) ... C) **IF** you make such huge jumps you would at least want to stick to a **stable LTE** version - the latest would currently be `LTS Release 2022.3.19f1` ... D) anything beyond depends on your exact errors => include them in your question!

Comment: My guess: Most probably something related to the packages being upgraded automatically - Unity doesn't expect you downgrading from higher versions so this is not built-in supported (and tbh even upgrading sometimes causes hickups) ... best guess: (after you make backups) delete all folders except `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` ... in particular `Library` and - in this case only - also delete the `Packages` folder. Then open your project in the older version and reinstall any missing packages - and then just hope there weren't any automatic API code changes - otherwise fix them one by one ;)